# Arduino (C language) parsing string with delimiter (input through serial interface)

Tags: c, string, parsing, arduino, delimiter

Arduino (C language) parsing string with delimiter (input through serial interface)

Didn't find the answer here :/

I want to send to my arduino through a serial interface (Serial.read()) a simple string of three numbers delimited with comma. Those three numbers could be of range 0-255.

Eg. 
`255,255,255`
`0,0,0`
`1,20,100`
`90,200,3`

What I need to do is to parse this string sent to arduino to three integers (let's say r, g and b).

So when I send 
    100,50,30 
arduino will translate it to

```
int r = 100
int g = 50
int b = 30
```

I tried lots of codes, but none of them worked. The main problem is to translate string (bunch of chars) to integer. I figured out that there will probably be strtok_r for delimiter purpose, but that's about it.

Thanks for any suggestions :)

Comment: atoi to turn it into a number

Comment: so, split it up by commas, and then atoi each bit

Comment: Why bother going through strings? Just send three bytes with the appropriate values.

Comment: If you are controlling the orginal sent content, instead of sending strings, why not just send 3 bytes? Then no parsing or commas needed.

Comment: Save the bytes into a unsigned char[], then you can easily access them.

Comment: @jdh Can you post your idea as an answer? Would like to see how that looks as I am trying to get RGB values and would like to use **BYTES** instead of **STRING** since it takes a lot of space and im using an **ATTINY85**.

Comment: @Kevin Can you post your idea as an answer? Would like to see how that looks as I am trying to get RGB values and would like to use **BYTES** instead of **STRING** since it takes a lot of space and im using an **ATTINY85**.

Answer (score 27):

To answer the question you actually asked, String objects are very powerful and they can do exactly what you ask. If you limit your parsing rules directly from the input, your code becomes less flexible, less reusable, and slightly convoluted.

Strings have a method called indexOf() which allows you to search for the index in the String's character array of a particular character. If the character is not found, the method should return -1. A second parameter can be added to the function call to indicate a starting point for the search. In your case, since your delimiters are commas, you would call:

```
int commaIndex = myString.indexOf(',');
//  Search for the next comma just after the first
int secondCommaIndex = myString.indexOf(',', commaIndex + 1);
```

Then you could use that index to create a substring using the String class's substring() method. This returns a new String beginning at a particular starting index, and ending just before a second index (Or the end of a file if none is given). So you would type something akin to:

```
String firstValue = myString.substring(0, commaIndex);
String secondValue = myString.substring(commaIndex + 1, secondCommaIndex);
String thirdValue = myString.substring(secondCommaIndex + 1); // To the end of the string
```

Finally, the integer values can be retrieved using the String class's undocumented method, toInt():

```
int r = firstValue.toInt();
int g = secondValue.toInt();
int b = thirdValue.toInt();
```

More information on the String object and its various methods can be found int the [Arduino documentation](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject).

Comment: `thirdValue` will always return 0.

Comment: There is a mistake, change this: `String thirdValue = payload.substring(secondCommaIndex+1);`

Answer (score 12):

Use `sscanf`;

```
const char *str = "1,20,100"; // assume this string is result read from serial
int r, g, b;

if (sscanf(str, "%d,%d,%d", &r, &g, &b) == 3) {
    // do something with r, g, b
}
```

Use my code here if you want to parse a stream of string ex: `255,255,255 0,0,0 1,20,100 90,200,3`[Parsing function for comma-delimited string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35150262/parsing-function-for-comma-delimited-string/35153813#35153813)

Comment: I like this solution for 2 reasons: 1. It is short. 2. It has fail/success result.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest, I think, is using `parseInt()` to do this task:

```
void loop(){
    if (Serial.available() > 0){
        int r = Serial.parseInt();
        int g = Serial.parseInt();
        int b = Serial.parseInt();
    }
}
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I think you  want to do something like this to read in the data:

```
String serialDataIn;
String data[3];
int counter;


int inbyte;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  counter = 0;
  serialDataIn = String("");
}

void loop()
{
    if(serial.available){
        inbyte = Serial.read();
        if(inbyte >= '0' & inbyte <= '9')
            serialDataIn += inbyte;
        if (inbyte == ','){  // Handle delimiter
            data[counter] = String(serialDataIn);
            serialDataIn = String("");
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
        if(inbyte ==  '\r'){  // end of line
                handle end of line a do something with data
        }        
    }
}
```

Then use atoi() to convert the data to integers and use them.

Answer (score 1):

This is great!

The last comment about "thirdvalue = 0" is true from the code given in the most upvoted response by @dsnettleton. However, instead of using "lastIndexOf(',');" , the code should just add a "+1" to "secondCommaIndex" like @dsnettleton correctly did for commaIndex+1 (missing +1 is probably just a typo from the guy).

Here is the updated piece of code

```
int commaIndex = myString.indexOf(',');
int secondCommaIndex = myString.indexOf(',', commaIndex+1);
String firstValue = myString.substring(0, commaIndex);
String secondValue = myString.substring(commaIndex+1, secondCommaIndex);
String thirdValue = myString.substring(secondCommaIndex+1); //To the end of the string
```

Example)

For a myString = "1,2,3"

- commaIndex = 1  (Searches from index 0, the spot taken by the character 1, to the location of the first comma)
- secondCommaIndex = 3  (Searches from index 2, the spot taken by the character 2, to the location of the next comma)
- firstValue reads from index 0-1 = "1"
- secondValue reads from index 2-3 = "2"
- thirdvalue reads from index 4-4(the last index spot of the string) = "3"

Note: Don't confuse INDEX with the LENGTH of the string. The length of the string is 5. Since the String indexOf counts starting from 0, the last index is 4.

The reason why just

```
String thirdValue = myString.substring(secondCommaIndex);
```

returns 0 when using .toInt() is because thirdValue = ",3" and not "3" which screws up toInt().

ps. sorry to write all the instructions out but as a mech eng, even I sometimes would like someone to dumb down code for me especially having been in consulting for the past 7 years. Keep up the awesome posting! Helps people like me out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For n number delimited in string

```
int end;
while((end=str.indexOf(","))!=-1){
  String num = str.substring(0,end);
  str= asc.substring(end+1,str.length());
  Serial.println(num);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The new SafeString Arduino library (available via the library manager) provides an stoken() method and a toLong() method which handles this case and avoids the heap fragmenation problems of the String class.

see
 https://www.forward.com.au/pfod/ArduinoProgramming/SafeString/index.html

 for a detailed tutorial

```
#include "SafeString.h"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  createSafeString(appCmd, 50);  // large enough for the largest cmd
  createSafeString(token1, 10);
  createSafeString(token2, 10);
  createSafeString(token3, 10);
  long r; 
  long g;
  long b;
  
  appCmd = "1,20a,100"; 
 
  token1.clear();token2.clear();token3.clear(); // clear any old data
  size_t nextIdx = 0; 
  nextIdx = appCmd.stoken(token1, nextIdx, ",");
  nextIdx++; //step over delimiter
  nextIdx = appCmd.stoken(token2, nextIdx, ",");
  nextIdx++; //step over delimiter
  nextIdx = appCmd.stoken(token3, nextIdx, ",");
  nextIdx++; //step over delimiter
  // now parse the numbers
  bool have3ValidNumbers = true;
  if (!token1.toLong(r)) {
    have3ValidNumbers = false;
    Serial.print("Red number invalid:");Serial.println(token1);
  }
  if (!token2.toLong(g)) {
    have3ValidNumbers = false;
    Serial.print("Green number invalid:");Serial.println(token2);
  }
  if (!token3.toLong(b)) {
    have3ValidNumbers = false;
    Serial.print("Blue number invalid:");Serial.println(token3);
  }
  if (have3ValidNumbers) {
    Serial.print("The values are ");
    Serial.print(" r:");Serial.print(r);
    Serial.print(" g:");Serial.print(g);
    Serial.print(" b:");Serial.print(b);
    Serial.println();
  }
}

void loop() {
}
```

The output for this input *"1,20a,100"* is 
**Green number invalid:20a**

The 'standard' toInt() method would have returned 1 20 100 as the result.
For an input like "1,a,50" the 'standard' toInt() method would return 1  0  100
The SafeString toLong() method does more error checking when attempting to convert a string to an integer.

You should also add checks for <0 and >255 to ensure the input is valid range

Answer (score -3):

@cstrutton -Excellent  suggestion on using 'indexOf' . it saved me a ton of time for my project. One minor pointer though,

I noticed the thirdvalue did not get displayed (was coming back as ZERO). Upon playing with it little-bit and going through the doc at http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringIndexOf
I realized, I can use lastIndexOf for the last value.

Here are two lines of modifications that provided correct third value.

```
int lastCommaIndex = myString.lastIndexOf(',');

String thirdValue = myString.substring(lastCommaIndex+1); // To the end of the string
```

Answer (score -3):

```
    String myString = "dfsdfgsafhffgsdvbsdvdsvsdvsdsdfdfsdsff|date|recipt|weight|time|date|";

    // the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
    void setup() {                
        Serial.begin(9600); 
    }


// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
 int Index1 = myString.indexOf('|');
int Index2 = myString.indexOf('|', Index1+1);
int Index3 = myString.indexOf('|', Index2+1);
int Index4 = myString.indexOf('|', Index3+1);
int Index5 = myString.indexOf('|', Index4+1);
int Index6 = myString.indexOf('|', Index5+1);
String secondValue = myString.substring(Index1+1, Index2);
String thirdValue = myString.substring(Index2+1, Index3);  
String fourthValue = myString.substring(Index3+1, Index4); 
String fifthValue = myString.substring(Index4+1, Index5); 
String firstValue = myString.substring(Index5+1, Index6); 
//Serial.println(Index1);
//
Serial.println(secondValue);
Serial.println(thirdValue);
Serial.println(fourthValue);
Serial.println(fifthValue);
Serial.println(firstValue);
delay(14000);
    }
```

Comment: add some description.. So that someone can understand the answer..!!